# fatal: unsafe repository ('<repository path>' is owned by someone else) after reinstalling Windows and Git

Tags: windows, git

After reinstalling Windows and Git, I get this error message on my **own**, locally checked out repositories (they were checked out before reinstalling Windows / kept on a separate disk partition):

> fatal: unsafe repository ('' is owned by someone
> else) To add an exception for this directory, call:
>
> ```
>     git config --global --add safe.directory <repository path>
> ```

I guess Git created a new identity for me on its new installation. How can I get back my old identity? I still have a backup of my old Windows installation so I guess I can somehow extract my identity from there?

Comment: The "right" fix will be to fix your ID, as in [joanis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72594181/1256452), but you can temporarily instruct Git to proceed anyway with the `safe.directory` directive from above.

Answer (score 1):

Windows would have created a new identity for you, not Git. Git is telling you that the owner if the files is not you based on what it sees on the file system.

In Git bash, if you type `id`, it'll output something like

```
uid=123456(<username>) gid=234567 groups=234567
```

and if you do `ls -la` in one of your Git sandboxes, you'll see something like `<username> 234567` as part of the listing for each file.

Do the username and id match between these two commands? If not, that's the source of your problem: Windows changed your id when you re-installed it.